# Comparing first row with 2nd row 2nd with 3rd and so on

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table. I want to compare each row with next row till all rows. If matched I need to display only mismatch values.

TABLE_A

1. ```
   A      B      C
   ```
2. ```
   A      B      D
   ```
3. ```
   E      A      E
   ```
4. ```
   A      C      E
   ```

..
..
..
nth

Output should be

1. ```
   A         B         C
   ```
2. ```
   NULL      NULL      D
   ```
3. ```
   E         A         E
   ```
4. ```
   A         C         NULL
   ```

..
..
..
nth

Comment: Have you had a look at `LAG`/`LEAD`?

Comment: Do you have a column that you can actually order by? Your question implies you don't, however, is the number bullet point actually part of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the SQL Lag function. This website explains how it works. Example 1 is very clear https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-lag-function-overview-and-examples/

> ```
> SELECT *, 
>        Lag(JoiningDate, 1) OVER(.
>        ORDER BY JoiningDate ASC) AS EndDate
> FROM @Employee;
> ```

makes:

> [image]